# How to use KML file in Google Maps for OFBiz?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, ofbiz

I'm trying to use KML file in Google Maps in OFBiz framework for a web application.I'm inputing the co-ordinates value in a array(list). So, how can i begin using Kml file in Google Maps??

I have inserted code of google maps in .ftl file

```
function initialize() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'satellite'
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        // Multiple Markers
        var markers = [
            ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
            ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
        ];

        // Info Window Content
        var infoWindowContent = [
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
            '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
            '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
            '</div>']
        ];

        // Display multiple markers on a map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
        var infoWindow1 = [];

        for( i = 0; i < farmerCropList.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(farmerCropList[i].latitude, farmerCropList[i].longitude);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: farmerCropList[i].farmerCropId
            });

            infoWindow1[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: '<div style="padding:5px;width:100%;height:auto;">' +
                                        '<div style="padding:5px;width:400px;font-size:16px;text-align:left">Farmer Name : '+(farmerCropList[i].firstName + farmerCropList[i].lastName)+'</div>'+
                                        '</div>'
              });



            var lastOpen = -1;
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    if (lastOpen > -1) {
                        infoWindow1[lastOpen].close();
                    }
                    return function(){
                    infoWindow1[i].open(map, marker);
                    }
                    lastOpen = i;
            })(marker, i));


            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
            this.setZoom(15);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    }
```

Comment: Try with `ftl` in OFBiz. In this format, you can use KML the same style as JSP does :)

Comment: @RongNguyen i have used in .ftl file to implement .

Comment: This issue comes from your Google API skill, not by OFBiz. Make sure you have included enough libraries :)

Comment: What is the KML file you are trying to load?

Comment: I got it !!! i included kml layer..its working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a KmlLayer

see this google developer sample

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml